# Unable to Access MySQL from Command Line

Tags: mysql, bash, mamp

Using MAMP 4.2.1

My bash profile:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin
```

Things tried and results:

```
mysql
=>ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'jessier'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

mysql -u root -p
=>Enter password: (*mypassword)
=> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql -u root -p
=>Enter password: (*mypassword)
    => ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock /tmp/mysql.sock
```

(Attempt again using previous commands, same error messages. Restarted terminal, restarted server, tried with servers both on and off to no success. MAMP running fine in /phpmyadmin.)

Comment: Are you restarting the server from the terminal or from the gui?  At least for me, the gui is unreliable.  If you haven't tried it yet, `sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop` then `sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start`

Comment: are you using your password or the root password?

Comment: Tried with both. GUI is available, command line not. And when I try sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop says command not found.

Comment: You might have a directory with a version number attached to it.  Try to locate your server file.  For example, if the directory happens to be in  /usr/local/ (9 times out of 10 it is) once you get there, list the folders and see if your have a mysql folder in there.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: SOLVED. Removed MAMP and did a fresh install. Once server started, ran:

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql --host=localhost -uroot -proot
```

Success.